Check and give a value if one of the rows has a value of false in mysql
I have a table with two columns of loop results as below:



ORDER_ID
STATUS




ORD001
YES


ORD001
NO


ORD001
NO


ORD001
YES


ORD002
NO


ORD002
NO



what I want to get is to get all rows "ORD001" and check if one of the rows has NO value in STATUS then it will be "False". if all rows are YES then it will be "True".



ORDER_ID
STATUS




ORD001
YES


ORD001
NO


ORD001
NO


ORD001
YES



The table above is "FALSE"



ORDER_ID
STATUS




ORD001
YES


ORD001
YES


ORD001
YES


ORD001
YES



and if the table is as above then the value is "TRUE".
$query02 = "SELECT ORDER_UID, STATUS FROM order_product WHERE ORDER_UID = '".$data['ordercode']."'";
$getdata = mysqli_query($conn, $query02);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getdata)){
   //Update Transaction is Completed
   if($row['STATUS'] == "YES"){
    $query05 = "UPDATE order_transaction SET ORDER_STATUS  = 'TRUE' WHERE ORDER_UID = '".$row['ORDER_UID']."'";
    $sql05 =  mysqli_query($conn, $query05) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
   }
}

My code successfully updated to "TRUE" even though ORD001 had one of the values ​​'NO'.
can you help me to understand how this works?
and sorry for my english to explain this.

"My code successfully updated to "TRUE" even though ORD001 had one of the values ​​'NO'." - and where exactly do you think you checked, whether any of the rows has a NO value? You aren't, instead you are making an update every single time you encounter a YES value.

'what I want to get is to get all rows "ORD001" and check if one of the rows has NO value in STATUS then it will be "False". if all rows are YES then it will be "True".' - so go and select only records with status=NO to begin with. If there are any, you want to update your corresponding order_transaction table entry with FALSE, else TRUE. (You might want to add LIMIT 1 to your query, because the only info you need is whether there is at least one record, but not their actual number or even the individual records.)

Total shot in the dark. I'm not a PHP expert by any means.  But is there a misplaced parenthesis by chance?
This line:
if( $row['STATUS']) == "YES"{

Should it be:
if( $row['STATUS'] == "YES") {

Otherwise, depending on how PHP parses, I could imagine the remaining lines running simply because $row['STATUS'] evaluates to true.
Anyway, like I said, total shot in the dark.  Your mileage may vary.

ow sorry thats my mistake. I will change it.

it was a typo when I edited my code here. in my project I have got the value 'TRUE' but the main problem is that it will value 'TRUE' even though one of ORD001 has the value 'NO'

This will return YES only if all rows have a status of YES:
SELECT ORDER_UID, IF(MIN(STATUS='YES'),'YES','NO') STATUS
FROM order_product
WHERE ORDER_UID='ORD001'
GROUP BY ORDER_UID


You should read these articles:

mysqli error reporting
general error handling in PHP
Mysqli tutorial, particularly section on prepared statements

You should find them useful and it will lead to cleaner code as you stop scattering die calls throughout your code.
You could make your current approach work by trying to select a single row with STATUS = 'NO'.
$query02 = "SELECT STATUS FROM order_product WHERE ORDER_UID = ? AND STATUS = 'NO' LIMIT 1";
$getdata = mysqli_execute_query($conn, $query02, [$data['ordercode']]);

// if there is a row to fetch we know there is a 'NO'
$new_order_status = mysqli_fetch_row($getdata) ? 'FALSE' : 'TRUE';

$query05 = 'UPDATE order_transaction SET ORDER_STATUS = ? WHERE ORDER_UID = ?';
$sql05 = mysqli_execute_query($conn, $query05, [$new_order_status, $data['ordercode']]);

Or similar, using the query suggested by ysth:
$query02 = "SELECT IF(MIN(STATUS = 'YES'), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS STATUS FROM order_product WHERE ORDER_UID = ?";
$result = mysqli_execute_query($conn, $query02, [$data['ordercode']]);

// there will always be one row with one column so we fetch the column directly
$new_order_status = mysqli_fetch_column($result);

$query05 = 'UPDATE order_transaction SET ORDER_STATUS = ? WHERE ORDER_UID = ?';
$sql05 = mysqli_execute_query($conn, $query05, [$new_order_status, $data['ordercode']]);

Alternatively, instead of SELECT followed by UPDATE you could use a single UPDATE statement:
$query02 = <<<SQL
        UPDATE order_transaction tx
        SET tx.ORDER_STATUS = (SELECT CASE MIN(STATUS) WHEN 'YES' THEN 'TRUE' WHEN 'NO' THEN 'FALSE' END FROM order_product WHERE ORDER_UID = tx.ORDER_UID)
        WHERE tx.ORDER_UID = ?
        SQL;
$getdata = mysqli_execute_query($conn, $query02, [$data['ordercode']]);

Storing YES/NO or TRUE/FALSE as strings in your database is just wasting space over using a TINYINT with just 0 or 1. The same goes for your ORDER_UID strings, store the integer values and then decorate with ORD prefix and padding for display purposes, if needs be.
